# How to make Unity Play Mode NOT force screen focus to Unity Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The Unity project I work on takes a moment to run after pushing Play. Often times I'll hit play, and while it's thinking, will click into another window (I'm always looking up data I need to verify in the game). So while I'm looking at something else or typing something, Unity will wrest control of the screen and force the cursor into Unity editor and make Unity the focused window on my screen once Play gets going.

Is there a way to turn this off? I want to be able to hit play in Unity editor, and be able to ignore it and have it run like any other window, doing its thing where I left it. I don't want play mode to force the Unity editor to become the focused window.

Comment: This is strange, my default behaviour is that when I click play and focus another window, Unity won't steal focus, but it will just go into pause (as it does everytime it's in play mode and you change window focus to another one), it will just make the Unity taskbar flash.

Comment: Mine keeps running when I focus to another window. Which is what I want it to do in that case.

I know my use case is an edge case, but I almost always hit the Play button, and during the time it takes Unity to fully get going, I'm off to another window- Hip Chat, looking something up, whatever. Then once Unity is done setting things up a few moments later the Unity editor displays itself over whatever window I was looking at, stealing the cursor's focus as well. I don't want it to do that

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of any help, I can't manage to reproduce your problem on my PC - are we talking about v5.5.0f3 64bit, or another version?

Comment: I'm on version 5.3.4p4

Comment: I checked the 5.5 release notes, there's this one that I guess fixes the problem: _Editor: Fix clicking Player Settings button in Build Settings window not giving focus to inspector. (720992)_. So, upgrade to 5.5. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In recent Unity versions, the Game window has a dropdown that says *Play Focused*, change it to *Play Unfocused*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the version 2022.3.4f1.
To have Unity play while you're focusing another window, you can go to
Edit on the top left of the screen > Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation > and check the Run In Background Checkbox
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhgr6.png)